# How to apply force or line load in an angle in ABAQUS

Tags: finite-element-analysis

A question in ABAQUS (may seem very basic). How to apply concentrated force or line load at an angle in ABAQUS? ABAQUS only gives option to specify components in X, Y, Z directions for a concentrated force. So resolving force is only option? Can anyone comment?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple matter of understanding that force is a vector quantity.  Given known angle(s), calculate the components in the coordinate system of choice.

You might really be asking "If I know that my force is normal to a surface in its local coordinate system, how do I calculate its components in global (x, y, z) system?"

If that's your real question, it's just a [vector transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) from the surface normal coordinate system to the global (x, y, z).  The surface coordinate system should be `(n, t, z)` where `n` = unit vector normal to the surface, `z` = unit vector out of the plane, `t` = unit vector tangential to the surface defined by the cross product `t = z X n`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I said in question, is resolving the force only option, I meant the same thing i.e. affine transformation.  I want to know that whether ABAQUS provides any way to apply force at angle according to nodal coordinate system. I know that in ANSYS, one could apply force in nodal coordinates.

Comment: Usually it's more convenient to use a traction loading (aka pressure) which is normal to the surface.  Let ABAQUS do the transformation for you.  If you have a spherical shell with a pressure loading on the outside, you wouldn't apply the load with individual forces on nodes.  You'd apply a uniform pressure on the surface.

Comment: You are right. But if I have many concentrated forces at angles, then resolving them each along global coordinates will be tedious. So I was searching for some way to apply force at some angle with respect to global coordinates.

Comment: My advice is to write code to preprocess your stuff.  That's what I usually did when I did FEA for a living and was faced with tedious stuff like this.  Write it once, use it forever.  As far as I know there is no easy way.  Get a shovel and start digging.

Answer (score 0):

Concentrated forces are applied in the nodal coordinate system. You can use a TRANSFORM on the nodes. For example, to apply a radial load away from the Z axis (lifted from http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/programs/fe/abaqus/faq68/abaqusf7.html)

```
*TRANSFORM, TYPE=C, NSET=CID1
          0.,          0.,          0.,          0.,          0.,          1.
**
*NSET, NSET=CID1
       1,       2,       3,       4,       5
**
**
** radial force
**
*CLOAD, OP=NEW
       1, 1,          1.
       2, 1,          1.
       3, 1,          1.
       4, 1,          1.
       5, 1,          1.
```

In general though, you'll still need vector components to define the rotated coordinate system for *TRANSFORM but if your angles are uniform in a cylindrical or spherical coordinate system or many nodes have the same angle but different loads, then this will save a lot of tediousness.